# Are there 10 numbers with this property?

Tags: prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

I came across a problem that required finding the first 10 numbers (n > 2) with the following property:

all positive numbers x less than n that have GCD(x, n) = 1 should be prime

example:

12 is such a number because all x that have GCD(x, 12) = 1 are prime (those being 5, 7 and 11)

15 isn't such a number because GCD(4, 15) = 1 for instance, but 4 isn't a prime number

I wrote a simple program that tries to look after such numbers, the first eight being:

3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 18, 24 and 30 being the last found (either because the next one is a really big number or because there isn't another one).

So my guess right now is that there aren't more than 8, which brings me to my question. Is there a way you can prove there aren't more than 8 using math? (or work some sort of logic that tries to find out how big would the next one be if there is)

Comment: Observe that if $p$ is a prime such that $p<\sqrt{x}$, then $p\mid x$ since otherwise $p^2$ violates the condition.

Comment: @Yanko $\gcd(49,60)=1$.

Comment: Are you sure about the $n > 2$? The ten numbers with that property (where, however, one must constrain $x$ to $1 < x < n$) are the eight you have, plus $1$ and $2$.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675546/show-that-only-finitely-many-positive-integers-n-have-the-property-that-for-al).

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A048597